# 生成される図のファイル名

Tags: sphinx

はじめまして、よろしくお願いします。

blockdiagやplantUML拡張で生成される図のファイル名を固定する方法はありますか？
blockdiag-03f29426fa631bca7b8304618538c8e37ce62f38.png
のようなファイル名になり、記述を変えるごとに別の名前で生成されていきます。

使用環境
Windows10
Python 3.6.4
Sphinx 1.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

実装コードはこのあたりです。
https://bitbucket.org/blockdiag/blockdiag/src/07f96892bfda92b84f624afab987015f26ff7ff0/src/blockdiag/utils/rst/nodes.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#nodes.py-49

残念ながら、ファイル名を指定する方法は提供されていないようです。